# How to use UIViewAnimationCurve options in CAAnimation

Tags: ios, swift3, caanimation

I am using a CAAnimation in a CAShapeLayer to simply animate a line that strokes from left to right (it's just a cut-down version of a more complex program).   I have slowed it down to show that the beginning quarter is almost instantaneous, and then the rest animates normally.

I have seen that one can use UIView.animate's options to set the UIViewAnimationCurve options (for instance, .EaseIn or .Linear).   Is it possible to set these options when embedding a CAAnimation in a CAShapeLayer?   And is it necessary to create the animation every time you want to run it, or is there a "run animation" command?

Below is my cut-down code:

```
    // the containing UIView is called mainView

    mainView.layer.sublayers = nil

    // create a line using a UIBezierPath

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 100))

    // create a CAShapeLayer

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 1024)
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 100
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

    // create the animation

    mainView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "LetterStroke")

    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 1
    animation.duration = 10

    shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "animation")
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `timingFunction` property of `CABasicAnimation`. There is a constructor that accepts [these](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatimingfunction/predefined_timing_functions) predefined timing functions like

```
 animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, and is much appreciated.  I actually found that the problem lay elsewhere, as you can see below, but you did, in fact, answer my question as stated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the line animation appeared to start a quarter of the way in.   I neglected to put what turned out to be the offending line of code in my question.

shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

This, combined with the lineWidth of 100, made the line start approximately a quarter of the way from the beginning.   I made the lineWidth smaller, and it worked fine.